# Put a message instead of an event into an Azure Event Grid

Tags: azure-eventgrid

This question is about the correct or at least intended usage of Azure Event Grid.

In the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/compare-messaging-services it says:

> The event message has the information you need to react to changes in services and applications. Event Grid isn't a data pipeline, and doesn't deliver the actual object that was updated.

In my use case, I want to update a search index after an entity has changed.

```
Entity changes -> [Azure Event Grid -> Azure function] -> update search index
```

For this case, I want to put the complete entity into the Azure Event Grid, so I can simply put the entity from the event into the search index (using an Azure function). But well, at least the documentation says to not do so.
As far as I can see I should use Azure Service Bus for doing so, but well, I don't get why I should not put the complete entity into Azure Event Grid.

Comment: Azure Event Grid is a loosely decoupled Pub/Sub **PUSH eventing model** to distribute your source interest in reliable *Fan-Out* and/or *Fan-In* patterns. Basically, you can put your entity state (object) into the event message, but AEG doesn't guarantee an order of the event messages, also subscribers are full transparent each other and they are not balanced, therefore your entity state (object) will be multicast to all active subscribers on the specific source interest (topic) using the Fan-Out manner.

Comment: Thanks for explanation.
Is Azure Service Bus not a PUSH eventing model?

Comment: Azure Service Bus is a loosely decoupled Pub/Sub **PULL messaging model**.

Comment: Had not yet heard of the difference push/pull, whom else is interested, see https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#push_pull

Comment: I do recommend to read the doc https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-overview, where you can see, the each service bus entity has a receiver for pulling a message. In the opposite, to the AEG, there are no listeners/receivers in the AEG, each subscription has an *event handler* which it represents an event destination resource. Note, that using the event handler resource such as a storage queue, we can distribute an event in the **Push-PushAck-Pull** manner, but in this scenario, the message pulling from the queue is not a part of the AEG model.